# Why doesn't it work when I try to start application using erl -s

Tags: erlang

Something like

```
erl -s crypto start -s application start public_key
```

works for crypto but not application:start(..). Typically I have call application supervisor but not application itself. What's the normal way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The -s flag expects

> Module Fun Arg1 Arg2 ..

and executes it as

> module:fun([Arg1, Arg2, ..]).

So, it passes the arguments as a list.

When running `-s application start public_key` it wil call `application:start([public_key])`, which isn't supported. This works: `application:start(public_key)`

I did not found a workaround for it without creating a module that contains a function to start up the public_key application, like:

> -module(myapp).
>
> -export([start/1]).
>
> start([App]) ->     application:start(App).

And call it like

> erl -s crypto start -s myapp start public_key

Comment: You could also run `erl` with `-eval "application:start(public_key)"`